# Bash Script - Invalid Arithmetic Operator

Tags: linux, bash, unix

with the below code I keep getting the following errors:

```
#!/bin/bash
    sourceFile="file1.log"
    targetFile="/etc/network/interfaces"
    numLines=$(wc -l ${sourceFile})
    if (( counter >= "$numLines" || ! -f "${sourceFile}" )); then
            echo "invaild file"
            exit 0
    fi
    while [ "$counter" -le "$numLines" ]; do
            sed -i "${2} s/.*/wireless-key s: $(sed -n "${counter}"p <<< "${sourceFile}")/" "${targetFile}"
            counter=$((counter + 1))
    done
```

with the above code I keep getting the following errors:

```
  > ./2test.sh: line 5: ((: counter >= 12 file1.log || ! -f file1.log : syntax error: invalid arithmetic operator (error token is ".log || !
  > -f file1.log ") ./2test.sh: line 9: [: : integer expression expected
```

Comment: `wc -l ${sourceFile}` prints `12 file1.log`, so that's the value of `$numLines`. `numLines="$(wc -l < "${sourceFile}")"` should give you just the number (the quotes are free this week, enjoy).

Comment: Seems like `echo 'invalid file' >&2; exit 1` would be more appropriate.  Errors should be printed to stderr, and the script ought to return non-zero if it fails.

Comment: Also `! -f "${sourceFile}"`  is not valid code in `(())`, maybe try it in square brackets i.e `(( counter >= "$numLines" )) ||  [[ ! -f "${sourceFile}" ]]`

Comment: Thank you Biffen, William Pursell & 123

Comment: I've just got the last error still, do you know anything on that one?

Comment: @spbr Is `$counter` set to anything?

Comment: @Biffen no, not currently

Comment: @spbr Then how do you expect `[ "$counter" -le "$numLines" ]` to work?! Or `(( counter >= "$numLines" […] ))` for that matter?

Comment: Thank you, @WilliamPursell and Biffen, having the trouble with this line of code ' sed -i "${lineNumber} s/.*/wireless-key s:" "$(sed -e ${counter}"p <<< "${sourceFile}")" ${targetFile}" ', everytime I get rid of the error it doesn't print the contents of the sourceFile to the targetFile. Thank you

Comment: @Biffen `(( counter >= ... ))` will default `counter` to 0 if it isn't yet set (unlike `(( $counter >= ... ))`).

Comment: @chepner Well, it still makes the comparisons rather useless.

Comment: @spbr That's unrelated to the issue of this question, so post a new question with more details about that other issue.

Answer (score 3):

<sup><sup>Turning my comment into an answer.</sup></sup>

`wc` with an explicit filename includes that filename in the output, so:

```
wc -l ${sourceFile}
```

Prints:

```
12 file1.log
```

That's then the value of `$numLines`.

The clue is in the error message: It includes the expanded expression:

```
> ./2test.sh: line 5: ((: counter >= 12 file1.log || ! -f file1.log : syntax error[…]
                                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

You can avoid getting that filename by redirecting the file's contents to `wc` instead:

```
numLines="$(wc -l < "${sourceFile}")"
```

<sup>(The added quotes are thrown in as it's a good habit. (No, they're not *strictly* necessary in this case.) (And yes, the qoutes are correct, even if SO's syntax highlighter doesn't quite seem to understand them.)</sup>

There are other issues in the script (mentioned in the comments), but one question at a time. I will take the opportunity to recommend [ShellCheck](http://www.shellcheck.net), though.

Comment: nit: "piping" the file's contents can be done with `cat $sourceFile | wc -l` (UUOC), but there is no pipe involved with `wc -l < $sourceFile`.  A redirection is not a pipe.

Comment: @WilliamPursell Heh, lazy me. Fixed. Thanks!